# Objective-c no known class method for selector 'playAtTime'

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to program an alarm to go off at a user set time using `AVAudioPlayer` and `playAtTime` and when I use this code `[AVAudioPlayer playAtTime:dateTimeString];`
 to try and get it to play at the user set time, I get this error `no known class method for selector 'playAtTime'`. The rest of my code is as follows

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController()
 {
      AVAudioPlayer *_myPlayer;
 }
@end

@implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/drum01.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
_alarmPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];

}

-(IBAction) alarmSetButtonTapped:(id)sender {

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: dateTimePicker.date ];
NSLog( @"Set button tapped : %@", dateTimeString );

[AVAudioPlayer playAtTime:dateTimeString];

[self scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate: dateTimePicker.date];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

And the viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AvFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
  {
     IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dateTimePicker;
  }


 -(IBAction) alarmSetButtonTapped:(id)sender;

 @end
```

How do I fix this error and use `playAtTime`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-[AVAudioPlayer playAtTime:]` method is an instance method, not a class method, so it must be called on an instance (e.g, `_alarmPlayer`). Additionally, its argument is a `NSTimeInterval`, not a string.

In any case, this method does not do what you want here. It is used to start the player from a point other than its beginning; the argument indicates how far into the sample it should start. It does not schedule the audio sample to be played at a time in the future.